# Git: Ignore compiled Google Go

Tags: git, go, gitignore

My compiled Go code does not end with an extension on Linux.

Any tips for handling ignoring these in the .gitignore file?

Comment: Is it possible to ignore files by file/mime type with git?

Comment: Does google go really not use an extension for its compiled files? If yes that language hopefully dies really quickly (or actually never gets fully born)...

Comment: Is it fair to suggest that you should write and run `make clean` before doing your `git` work?

Comment: Well, it creates executables when building. So on windows we get a .exe file, while on Linux we get an ELF that does not have a file extension (at least by default).

Comment: Extending sarnold's comment, you could create a pre-commit hook to run `make clean` before every commit.

Comment: I think Sarnold and 3electrologo's suggestions are a good idea here. Using `go clean` I can wipe these from the current directory, but not subdirectories. There might be some functionality built into the clean package, but I need to take a look at the source http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/clean.go
EDIT: _The -r flag causes clean to be applied recursively to all the
    50 dependencies of the packages named by the import paths._ So this would work as long as the subdirectory was called by the toplevel elements.

Comment: @Matthew: Linux executables don't normally have extensions, no matter what language they're from. It's objects and libraries that do.

Comment: @Jefromi: correct. One thing I've done now is to add an entry such as `*.build` to my gitignore and then run build `go build -o prog.build prog` to build prog.

Comment: Both `go test` and `go install` typically (depends on your env) produce a binary outside the directory where the sources are. Why do you have to use `go build` inside your repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep your build products separate from your source code.  This has several advantages:

- you can start many different builds of the same code at the same time without creating multiple clones
- it's easy to be confident that you've really done a clean; `rm -rf objdir` will remove files that a buggy `make clean` will miss
- you can kick off a build from a read-only copy of the source tree (e.g., CD-ROM)
- you're less likely to accidentally commit generated files
- `git clean -dxf` will clean your source tree, but won't touch your built files

Note that GNU Automake and Make support a feature called [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html) to make it easy to separate the source tree from the build tree.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the `go` tool to build your code you can use the `-o` flag to specify the output file name, so you can for example use `go build -o bin/elf` and then add `bin/*` to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the names of the files in your `.gitignore`? Tedious, but it will work.

Comment: True, but then I might as well manually add each file to my git add routine. Was hoping someone might have a trick to do this in a more portable fashion.

Answer (score 3):

The `.gitignore` language isn't Turing complete.  It can only match fairly simple patterns.  This just means you need something else that can figure out what possible executables should be excluded. So, write a script that creates `.gitignore` based on the names of the executables that can be created.  If you want to be fancy, make an alias that runs it before `git add`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Ignore all files in the required directory except go files.

E.g assume your `main.go` and binary file with name main are in the same directory i.e `main/main.go` and `main/main`

Modify your `.gitignore` to ignore all files inside the main directory except files with the `.go` extension

```
main/*
!main/*.go
```