# How to compile .go file to specific directory, or to gitignore the binaries?

Tags: go

Right now I'll just run `go build __.go`, but I'm wondering if it's possible to have that file built in a subdirectory (e.g. a `/bin` folder). It would just make gitignoring the binary files a lot cleaner, and right now I'm not really sure what else is a good approach as I'm also struggling to create a working gitignore exception rule that isn't just "Ignore all files, except .go files".

My current solution is naming the binary files every time I build them (e.g. `go build -o hello.bin hello.go`), but this seems laborious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Ignore compiled Google Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952061/git-ignore-compiled-google-go)

Answer (score 22):

you can use the `-o` flag.

1. `cd` to the directory where you have the `main.go` file.
2. use this command - `go build -o DirectoryPath`

Where `DirectoryPath` is the location where you want to create the binary file to.

Comment: It's also possible to do this the other way (which does not require the -o flag):

1. cd to the directory where you want to store the binary

2. `$go build /path/to/source/file.go`

Comment: I find your solution is very misleading, I have specified the DirectoryPath but I have couldn't find the directory I been specified. Is it the path appended from the $GOROOT ? or $GOPATH ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `go build *.go`, you can do following:

1. Setup `Go workspace`, using this official go resource: [How to write go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)
2. Define `GOBIN` and `GOPATH` environment variable.`GOBIN` environment variable will point to the directory where you want to store your executables.`GOPATH` environment variable will point to the directory, where you've setup `go workspace`.

Now, instead of doing `go build *.go`, you can use `go install {YourCodePath}`, where `{YourCodePath}`, is relative path of your code in go workspace. And if the build is successful, you can find your executable in directory, pointed by `GOBIN`.

Comment: Add to above answer, use 'go run _.go' during development to avoid generating executable binary in your source code path.